# WooCommerce - Add a button that links to the page body after Category Page Titles?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

I have a new website, that uses a large photo at the start of Category pages, with a product table underneath,

The problem is when you load the page you cannot see the product table and i'm worried people wont realise you need to scroll down to see the products.

Is it possible to add a button After the Category Page Title, that jumps them to the body of the page for example?

In my head it would look something like this:

"CATEGORY PAGE TITLE" -  [BUTTON WITH JUMP TO PAGE BODY]

As the jump would be to the body of the page, you could apply the same button to every category page in theory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your theme, the PHP code rendered could be very different and it's quite difficult to say which filter to use to inject a button.
But using jQuery, you could do this as in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/abraraamer/pen/NWmvWpM)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('.category-div').after('<a id="scroll-down" href="#">Scroll Down</a>');
   $('#scroll-down').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#products").offset().top
     }, 1000);
   });
});
```

You can add this Javascript part in some javascript file your child theme might be using or use Insert Headers And Footers plugin and paste the Javascript part in the header.